# Angularjs with Ajax response bind to a div

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have to implement angular inside a "ASP.net MVC/web api" project.
My challenge is that i have a single page type of application, with Main.vbhtml as main container. There is also a layout.vbhtml
All remaining page get display inside Main, by using ajax call and load inside a DIV.
I created a new page pagenew.vbhtml and put my angular content in there. When i click on the menu my ajax call return  the content of pagnew in response and bind to my div. We use this way because of the tabs (meaning i can open pagenew many time in tab control)
The problem is that my angular does not work at all. 

I render my angular code in layout.vbhtml   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ng")
Here is my ajax call and my angular

```
<script>function loadMyPage() {
$("#div1").load("http://localhost:52269/pagenew.vbhtml");}</script>
```

My pagenew.vbhtml is

```
                                <div ng-app>
                                    <p>{{ "Hello" + " World" }}</p>
                                    <p>{{ 2 + 4 }}</p>
                                </div>
```

and my Main page (container) has the div

```
<div id="div1" ></div>here
```

PS: i have the angular.js in the layout.vbhtml

> the result:{{ "Hello" + " World" }}{{ 2 + 4 }}

HELP! Please

Comment: when are you calling loadMyPage ?

Comment: When user click on the Menu of pagenew

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to add ng-controller="controller name" next to the ng-app. Do you have a controller?

Comment: Should it matter in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Angular runs once the DOM finished loading. In your case Angular doesn't know to start since your Angular code is inserted after the DOM finished loading when a button is clicked.

You need to run Angular manually by using `Bootstrap`

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.bootstrap($(this), ['myApp']); // in the function loadmyopage make it works
```